# Propagate changes inside module.install schema to database

Tags: 7, database

Using schema module, I was able to easily describe tables that I included in Drupal DB, by creating .install files to appropriate modules.

Now i have updated field descriptions for each field defined in schema, inside those .install files. How do I get those (and even more complex) changes to be propagated to DB ?

I do not care for module versions/update functions, as these modules are internal (used only for this site)

Comment: How much complex ?

Comment: You might not care for update_nnn functions but they are the answer to your question. There's no automated magic that will do it for you, you have to write code to make the updates. The contributed Schema module will help you work out what will need to go into them.

Comment: Agree with @AlfredArmstrong, unless you can justify your wish not to use update hooks with a technical reason (i.e. not because it's too much effort) then the answer is "Use update hooks", and the question rhetorical

Comment: Those are simple storage tables that i included in drupal db, previously they were outside main drupal db, but now is simpler maintenance.- wise to have all data in one db. Alfred, as i stated i already used schema module for quickstart. As this is internal i only wanted to sync  db and shema. There are no module versions to take care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During development this might be appropriate. If you make mistakes in the schema you may just want to start from scratch again. To do this you need to completely uninstall and reinstall the module. drush can make this faster.

This is dependent upon you implementing hook_uninstall which drops the schema - read deletes all data. 'drop table' in sql.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function hottopicsnotify_uninstall() {
  drupal_uninstall_schema(HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_VOTING_TABLE);
  drupal_uninstall_schema(HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_STATE_TABLE);

  variable_del(HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_CONTENT_TYPES_VAR);
  variable_del(HOTTOPICSNOTIFY_EDITORIAL_GROUP_VAR);
}
```

With Devel module installed run this on the command line:

```
* drush devel-reinstall -y hottopicsnotify
```

Without:

```
* drush dis -y hottopicsnotify
* drush pm-uninstall -y hottopicsnotify
* drush en -y hottopicsnotify
```

Comment: Thanx, this is method i need. Only I die not get if  uninstall hook you proposed destroys data too ?  I would like to keep data.

Comment: The uninstall hook definitely destroys data. It drops the table. Great method for automated testing/dev but you do need to go update hooks if you have live data.

Comment: then I need kind of one-time  in-place update or simply make changes to db by hand to reflect changes in schema declared in install, or to ignore drupal schema, as those custom modules are not going anywhere